# Code never terminates when trying to manipulate list result from pool multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, pool

I have a piece of code that runs various statistical operations in parallel using `pool` and `starmap`. If I try and manipulate the results list produced from this multi processed section however the code runs indefinitely.

I have removed the print length part and the code runs successfully and will terminate. I have also tried various methods such as `getvalues()`, `copy.copy()` and `copy.deepcopy()` to try and replicate the list and use this for manipulation but this, too ,has not worked.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def multiproc(tuple_list):
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        p = Pool(4) 
        end_tuple_list = p.starmap(get_stats, tuple_list)
        p.close()
        p.join()
        print(str(end_tuple_list))
        return end_tuple_list

res_tuple_list = multiproc(tuple_list))
print(str(res_tuple_list))
print('length is ' +str(len(res_tuple_list)))
```

I expected to be able to just use the resulting `res_tuple_list` like any ordinary `list`, but any time I try to manipulate it in any way the code never terminates and I think is stuck before the multiprocessing finishes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If possible, please could you edit your question to add an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example)? In particular, adding the imports you've used would help other users to reproduce your problem (e.g. what's `Pool`?)

Comment: `if __name__ == '__main__` should go *outside* `multiproc` just prior to `res_tuple_list = multiproc(tuple_list)`...

Comment: Observation: Having the `if __name__ == '__main__':` where it is will make `multiproc()` be a function that does nothing and returns `None` in all the sub-processes. Plus it causes/allows the rest of the module-level code to run in each.

Comment: Hi, Bakuriu - changing the position of if __name__ == '__main__' appears to have no effect.  martineau - this dosn't appear to be the case, multiproc() runs fine and returns the list it is supposed to, its only when I try and edit or use this list that I get in trouble.

Comment: Ok, so even more odd, is that I edited the function to write the data to excel instead. I can manually access the file but it comes up with NameError if I try and read it from Python. Even on a different computer !!!! how is this possible!?!?!